# SQL performance considerations when using 'case when' while updating a row

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I have been investigating ways to create a **DB2** SQL stored procedure (IBM iSeries) that updates a column based on few parameters. The parameters include column name (`@columnname`) to be updated, value (`@value`) to be updated and a where condition. Dynamic SQL is not an option.

Normally, I would do it like below.

```
IF @columnname = 'happy'
    UPDATE table SET col1 = @value

ELSE IF @ColumnName = 'sad'
    UPDATE table SET col2 = @value

ELSE IF @ColumnName = 'excited'
    UPDATE table SET col3 = @value
    
ELSE IF @ColumnName = 'name'
    UPDATE table SET col4 = @value
    
ENDIF
```

I am also successful in getting a single query working fine.

Here is my query:

```
update table 
set col1 = case when @columnname = 'happy' then @value else col1 end,
    col2 = case when @columnname = 'sad' then @value else col2 end,
    col3 = case when @columnname = 'excited' then @value else col3 end,
    col4 = case when @columnname = 'name' then @value else col4 end
where 
    [where condition]
```

The above one is updating the columns with existing value if the column name does not match. Would that be counted as overhead and which one of the above would be faster and less resource intensive?

Comment: It primary depends on your WHERE clause.

Comment: Performance is almost entirely dependent on your specific circumstances/setup. Try both ways and see which is faster (taking into account any caching, etc). Look at the EXPLAIN PLANs to see how the queries are being executed

Comment: A simple `CASE` clause like the one you include won't have any performance impact in the query. The key performance aspect you need to be aware of is the number of rows the query is reading. That is, tune the `WHERE` predicate appropriately.

Comment: The name of the operating system has been IBM i since 2008. The functionality available in IBM i is much greater than what was available 20 years ago on iSeries. Searching for iSeries will not give you the most current (useful) information.

Comment: Consider using the ACS Index Advisor to create appropriate indexes based on the usage statistics for your specific machine.